# RegEx: Capturar texto entre backslashs (Path)

Tags: regex

A ver si me podeis ayudar por favor. Estoy tratando de capturar con RegEx con el programa "The regex Coach"  los nombres de los directorios y subdirectorios de un path. Ejemplo:

> Projects\UP/PS (21063)\2789 (spain) / Ref/15\Email

Quiero capturar lo que hay entre los backslash exceptuando lo que hay entre los dos primeros. Me explico, quiero capturar lo siguente:

> UP/PS

He usado `([^\\]+)\s` (no funciona, me toma el espacio en blanco al final)

> (21063)

He usado `\((.*?)\)`  (funciona perfectamente)

> 2789 (spain) / Ref/15

No consigo saltar al segundo backslash

> Email

No consigo saltar al tercer backslash

Lo he intentado de mil maneras pero no lo consigo.
Espero que ahora este más claro.(Perdonad que la primera vez no me haya explicado mejor)
Gracias por la ayuda! :)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [help], [ask] y [faq]. En concreto, explica en tu pregunta (botón `editar`) qué has probado, y qué es lo que estás obteniendo.

Comment: gracias por el consejo!

Comment: Aún me queda cierta duda. Dices _Quiero capturar lo que hay entre los backslash exceptuando lo que hay entre los dos primeros_, entonces, ¿quieres extraer con la misma regex una serie de elementos de la string? Iría bien que detallaras exactamente cuáles quieres extraer o si bien quieres un regex diferente en cada caso.

Comment: Pues sigo sin entenderlo... Basándome en la ruta que has puesto ¿quieres extraer los cuatro elementos separados por \? (serían 1=`Projects`, 2=`UP/PS (21063)`, 3=`2789 (spain) / Ref/15`, 4=`Email`) ¿O tienes que separar dentro de cada elemento también por la barra `/`, o por el espacio? ¿O quieres sólo el último elemento? ¿Podrías poner en la pregunta cuál es el resultado deseado?

Comment: casi, serían 1=Projects (pero es tan  facil que lo he obviado), 2=UP/PS, 3=(21063), 4=2789 (spain) / Ref/15, 5=Email

Comment: No entiendo por qué coges "UP/PS" y "(21063)" por separada, pero luego "2789 (spain) / Ref/15" junto, cuando en ambos casos todo ello junto representa a un directorio.

Comment: Porque UP/PS y (21063) son dos variables diferentes que tengo que guardar por separado, eso ya no es cosa mia. Entiendo que sería más facil todo junto claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia !

Answer (score 2):

Una expresión muy fácil de entender es la siguiente:

```
(.*?)\\(.*?)\s(.*?)\\(.*?)\\(.*)
```

Hace uso del operador *non-greedy*, `*?`, y de grupos de captura. Significa lo siguiente:

- `(.*?)\\` Captura (grupo entre paréntesis) todos los caracteres que aparezcan (`.*`) hasta encontrar *el primer* backslash. El interrogante es el que hace que se detenga en el primero que encuentre (*non greedy*) en lugar de seguir hasta el último, que sería el comportamiento por defecto (*greedy*).
- `(.*?)\s` Análogo al anterior, captura (otro grupo) todos los caracteres hasta el primer espacio
- Y así cada uno de los grupos siguientes, salvo el último
- `(.*)` captura todo lo demás

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OSPjHX/2

Answer (score 1):

Mira a ver si esto es lo que buscas:

`([^\\]+)\\(\S+)\s([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\(.+)`

El resultado es:

```
Grupo 1 = Projects
Grupo 2 = UP/PS
Grupo 3 = (21063)
Grupo 4 = 2789 (spain) / Ref/15
Grupo 5 = Email
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pHzakm/6/)**

**Explicado:**

```
([^\\]+)   # Cualquier caracter salvo backslash 1 o más veces
\\         # backslash
(\S+)      # Cualquier caracter salvo espacios una o más veces
\s         # un espacio (incluye tabuladores, saltos de línea...)
([^\\]+)   # Cualquier caracter salvo backslash 1 o más veces
\\         # backslash
([^\\]+)   # Cualquier caracter salvo backslash 1 o más veces
\\         # backslash
(.+)       # Cualquier caracter salvo salto de línea
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Es perfecto!

Comment: Genial! Si te ha servido puedes marcarla como aceptada. Voy a documentar qué significa cada cosa